# Map exceptions to HTTP result

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

In a Play Framework controller, how do I map exceptions to HTTP result codes? For example, if calling any action results in a `MyDataLayer.EntityNotFound`, I want the HTTP result to be `404 not found`. **Does Play provide way to map exception types to HTTP result codes?**

(I am using Play 2.1.1.)

Comment: Do you mean play!1 or play!2?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that Play 1 and 2 are different beasts. I am using 2.1.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the `onError` callback defined in [play.api.GlobalSettings](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaGlobal) to handle the error and return appropriate HTTP status code.